# Onsen UI - reusable HTML fragments without Angular JS?

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm having a play around with Onsen UI and wondering if there's a way to define and include fragments of HTML when Onsen UI is being used without Angular JS?

For example, say I have two pages:

```
<ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <ons-toolbar-button onclick="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="fa-bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            <div class="center">Page 1</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <ons-toolbar-button onclick="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="fa-bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            <div class="center">Page 2</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <p>Page 2 content</p>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

The definition of the `<ons-toolbar-button>` is duplicated in both pages, so is there a mechanism to define the code fragment and inject it multiple times?

```
<ons-toolbar-button onclick="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="fa-bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
```

I know that using Angular this can be done using the [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) directive, but wondering if `<ons-template>` can somehow be used to do this without the need to go Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onsen UI 1.x is based on Angular, so it's hard to perform any action without using it.

What are you looking for is Onsen UI 2, which is based on Web Components. This means that it's totally agnostic (platform independent) and can be used in combination with any other framework. Actually it's in alpha release but it's already quite stable, a beta is expected very soon.

If you want to take a look at Onsen UI 2.0 you can:

- Check the latest version on [Onsen UI GitHub Repository](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI).
- Following the Quickstart procedure:

```sh
Quickstart
$ git clone http://github.com/OnsenUI/onsenui2-quickstart
$ cd onsenui2-quickstart
$ npm install && gulp serve
```

Comment: I'd come to the same conclusion that while Onsen UI 1.x claims to work without Angular, it is hard to use it without. v2.0 looks promising though - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Onsen UI 1.x doesn't claim to work without Angular, from the [Official Website](https://onsen.io): `Works with jQuery and AngularJS`

Comment: OK, I should've made myself clearer :) I meant Onsen UI 1.x claims to be usable without needing to use AngularJS constructs (i.e. you can use jQuery instead), but in fact, because it's built on Angular, you will at some point get stuck unless you use AngularJS e.g. needing ngInclude for including HTML fragments.

Comment: http://onsen.io/blog/onsen-ui-1-1-now-supports-jquery/: "web developers and designers without ANY AngularJS knowledge can now easily create beautiful hybrid mobile apps by using a window object version of Onsen UI."

Comment: Yes you are right, that sentence is a little bit confusing. At the top there is: `Onsen UI is still an AngularJS-based product, so you AngularJS hackers can continue to work with it as you normally do!`